# Underscore: group arrays with common second index value?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I found `_.groupBy` which works on objects by setting the property you want to group by but failed to find one for grouping an array of arrays.

```
arrays = [[0,'A','01010'],[4,'CD','1111'],[9,'FF','01010'],[6,'AX','01010']]
```

`.groupBy` yields nothing. I want to group by the 3rd value in each array.

what if I wanted to group by the 1st and 3rd array value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

_.groupBy() works on arrays or objects and allows you to specify an iterator function.

So this would group by the 3rd value in each array:

```
_.groupBy(arrays, function(num){return num[2]});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbu88/)

You could also use the 1st and 3rd values.  Exactly how you do that depends on how you want to combine the 2 values.  For instance this:

```
_.groupBy(arrays, function(num){return num[0]+'.'+num[2]});
```

Results in:

```
Object {0.01010: Array[1], 4.1111: Array[1], 9.01010: Array[1], 6.01010: Array[1]}
```

Given your data.

Or if you want to group by the third value and then group those results by the first value we can do this:

```
var out = _.groupBy(arrays, function(num){return num[2] });
out2={};
for (var prop in out) {
    out2[prop] = _.groupBy(out[prop],function(num) {return num[0]});
}
```

Which, with this data:

> arrays = [[0,'A','01010'],[4,'CD','1111'],[9,'FF','01010'],[6,'AX','01010'],[0,'AX','01010']]`

(so that we have a duplicate first entry) produces:

> 01010: Object 0: Array[2] 6:Array[1] 9: Array[1] 1111: Object 4: Array[1]

[demo of that](http://jsfiddle.net/tbu88/2/)

Comment: what if if I want to group by first and third?

Comment: See my updated answer- is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Be careful with `num[0]+num[2]` when grouping, some of the `num[2]` values have length four and some five so you could easily mash two distinct entries into one group.